# language speeds c vs objective c

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, performance

Ive been wondering, how much faster does c run than objective c? From what I understand c does run faster. I recently implemented a maths function in my app (written in standard c) in the hope that it would increase speed but does it really have that much of an effect?

cheers GC

Comment: Every C program is also an Objective-C program.  You might just as well ask if Objective-C is faster than Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, the algorithm is more important than the language. Having said that, there is no question that sometimes you have to optimize speed sensitive code. Every Objective-C method call requires more instructions than a plain-old C function call. Allocating objects in tight game loops is generally a bad idea as well and both iOS and Mac OS X calls tend to allocate a lot of objects.

In the old days, even a C++ method call would be too slow in a tight loop and C++ method calls are generally faster than Objective-C ones. On modern machines you don't see these sorts of problems as much, but they do still exist. Core Audio filters are a good example of code that needs to be written in plain C rather than Objective-C due to speed issues.

What I would recommend is to write your code using Objective-C and then run it to see if it's too slow. If so, run Instruments and see where you are spending most of your time. Then optimize that code using plain C, C++, or even assembly language (ok, just kidding about assembly language unless you're really pushing the envelope).

If you find the method call overhead within loops is slowing you down, you can optimize that by using plain C function calls, inline routines, unrolling the loop, or by using IMP pointers to avoid the method lookup overhead.

If you find that you are copying around data too much, you can optimize that by sharing buffers rather than copying them or maybe using [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy] rather than [NSData dataWithBytes], etc.

Sometimes you can optimize your graphics so they draw faster -- remove transparencies where they're not needed. Don't use CALayer shadows or blurs. All new Macs and many iOS devices have two or more CPU cores, so maybe you can offload some processing to the second core using threads. The list goes on and on.

So write your app first using Objective-C using reasonable algorithms and then optimize later when you see where the problems are. Don't do anything too stupid, like looping n^2 times through a large array in a tight loop, and you'll probably be ok for 90% of your code.

Comment: this is a bit misleading: C++ only adds overhead in case of virtual functions; for equivalent functionality in C, you'd have to implement your own vtables with the same performance characteristics; one of the design principles of C++ was to only pay for what you use, though there are exceptions to the rule (eg exceptions and RTTI with regards to code size)

Comment: That's very true -- C++ virtual functions have more overhead than non-virtual ones. Non-virtual functions have only a tiny amount of overhead - one extra parameter - that probably wouldn't be noticeable on any modern architecture. One area where C++ really can kill you though is code bloat if you use templates. The generated assembly code looks fast, but your code gets so large that you more quickly use up your instruction cache. Those kinds of speed issues are a real pain to track down and are very compiler dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Any language compiled to native code produces roughly the same instructions for the processor on any given task. The language itself does not imply any speed gains.  It is a common misconception that assembly is faster than C; C is faster than C++/Objective-C/What have you.

It all boils down to how you design your algorithm.  Of course there are exceptions to every rule.

Comment: language semantics matter for optimizability; there are reasons why Fortran is still around and why `restrict` was added to the C language

Comment: @Christoph +1, that however, would be the exception, rather than the rule.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with that. I wrote a color bitmap editor for Metrowerks a long time ago. At first, I used C++ virtual methods for accessing the buffer, but they were too slow. Non-virtual C++ methods were better, plain C functions better still, and inline code best of all. IIRC putting the functions in the same 32K CODE resource was faster than long jumps to other CODE resources. Of course, we've come a long way from 16MHz machines with no graphics acceleration hardware, but there are still cases in audio and video processing where you have to really optimize your code.

Comment: @EricS There are a few but well known features that will incur a performance penalty, notably dynamic behavior in OOP (rtti, virtual methods, safe typecasting). The rule of thumb is to design it properly, then leave it to the compiler.  If speed/performance is inadequate, use a profiler and apply optimizations as necessary. OPs question is stated broadly vs other compiled/bare metal languages.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no discernible difference in performance, especially for the type of code you describe which is essentially going to be C code compiled by the Objective-C compiler.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I read in a book that a games programmer writes as much code in c as possible to give the best performance. but I assume you would have to have a lot of c code vs objective-c to have a significant impact. Cheers

Comment: In case of game programming - is this really about C vs. Objective-C? Games often use scripting (in Python, Lua or other languages) which is way slower than compiled code, of course, and I think that the book you mentioned urged to use the compilable language instead of interpreted one (scripts).

Comment: Actually the book had a interview with a iPhone game developer who said that only about 20% of his app was objective-c the rest he wrote in standard c. He goes on to talk about how c runs faster. It may be that its possible to write more efficient code in c. I not an expert in games design, but this isn't the first time Ive heard this.

Comment: I think you'd need some examples of the code. If you are writing C and compiling it in an Objective C source file then you will get the same results. You may learn more by showing us some code. Without code we can only make very broad generalisations.

Answer (score 3):

It does boil down to the algorithm, but in assembly you can do things that C generally can not.  This includes organizing certain calls of the program so that pushes and pulls to the stack are not required.

If you need to divide by 2 for example a whole lot for a given task, in assembly you can simply do a register shift (or a couple shifts if it is a big number).  C will generally have to make a call, push and pull to the stack and the overhead alone makes it that much slower.

So yes, the above is technically an algorithm difference but the assembly programming allows you to do it. Then you apply the idea above to an array of mathematical functions and the speed difference can be pronounced.   To minimize the effect on C though is to obviously make the new assembly code into a library for C.  You still will have overhead as compared to straight assembler, but then you also get the best algorithm possible with the greater productivity of the higher level language.